# Mass assignment 2 levels deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My models looks something like this (stripped down to the bare minimum for this question):

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :array_resources
end
class ArrayResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :array_items
  has_many :array_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :array_items
end
```

Now, in my `Translation` model I have a method in which I call `array_resources.build(params)`, where `params` is an array of hashes, where each hash also contains an `:array_items` key, mapped to another array of hashes.

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ProjectsController#create
>
> ArrayItem(#69835262797660) expected, got Hash(#18675480)

Every other answer I read talked about using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but I already did that. Help?

Comment: Can you please add relevant codes from controller (create method) and view file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't assign to nested attributes `array_items` directly, but rather `array_items_attributes`.

You should make `:array_items_attributes` accessible:

```
class ArrayResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :array_items_attributes
```

Then in your params hash use the key `:array_items_attributes` instead of `:array_items`.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. However, how was I supposed to find that out? The documentation for `has_many` doesn't say anything about adding a `collection_attributes=` method. Where does it come from?

Comment: If you don't know what exactly you were looking for, the documentation can be tricky to find.  The attribute writer method is defined when you call `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, rather than when you create an association through `has_many`.  Here's a link to documentation (see the examples).  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for